# htaccess one OR two parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I want a URL like this:

www.mywebsite.com/user

So I do:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

it is working.

but SOMETIMES I need a secound parameter, like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/22 = user?id=22
```

or I need a secound parameter like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/images = user?pg=images
```

**notice that I can have an user/id or user/pg for different actions.**

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have 3 rules like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# to handle /user/22
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# to handle /user/images
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?pg=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# existing rule
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ index.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+)$ index.php?pg=$1
```